# BASH - Seeking name function then

Tags: bash

Someone please advise what it's called in bash function that reads the file and creates an array from it? Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736202/bash-read-file-line-into-array

Comment: Reading file and creating from file array...is a direct function, but I can not find it

Comment: @jitendra: The OP is explicitly asking for a built-in, which is different from the linked question (although the built-in might have been an answer for that, it wasn't provided).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently using windows so no bash here but this is how you do it:

```
value=0;

while read line
do
value=`expr $value + 1`;
arr[$value]=$line;

done < "myfile"
```

Comment: what makes you think exists a function that does it in bash?

Comment: alternatively: `declare -a arr=($(cat myfile))`

Comment: `$( < myfile)` is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the built-in `mapfile`.

From `help mapfile`:

```
mapfile: mapfile [-n count] [-O origin] [-s count] [-t] [-u fd] [-C callback] [-c quantum] [array]
    Read lines from the standard input into an indexed array variable.

    Read lines from the standard input into the indexed array variable ARRAY, or
    from file descriptor FD if the -u option is supplied.  The variable MAPFILE
    is the default ARRAY.

    Options:
      -n count  Copy at most COUNT lines.  If COUNT is 0, all lines are copied.
      -O origin Begin assigning to ARRAY at index ORIGIN.  The default index is 0.
      -s count  Discard the first COUNT lines read.
      -t                Remove a trailing newline from each line read.
      -u fd             Read lines from file descriptor FD instead of the standard input.
      -C callback       Evaluate CALLBACK each time QUANTUM lines are read.
      -c quantum        Specify the number of lines read between each call to CALLBACK.

    Arguments:
      ARRAY             Array variable name to use for file data.

    If -C is supplied without -c, the default quantum is 5000.  When
    CALLBACK is evaluated, it is supplied the index of the next array
    element to be assigned and the line to be assigned to that element
    as additional arguments.

    If not supplied with an explicit origin, mapfile will clear ARRAY before
    assigning to it.

    Exit Status:
    Returns success unless an invalid option is given or ARRAY is readonly or
    not an indexed array.
```