# Shell variable value substitution

Tags: shell, ksh

Heres the description of my issue, I have a while loop that takes values from a file

```
while read table
do
    schema="$(echo $table | cut -d'.' -f1)";
    tabname="$(echo $table | cut -d'.' -f2)";
    echo "$schema";
    echo "$tabname";
    echo $folder/$table_space"_auto_ddl"/$tabname"_AUTO_"$schema".sql.tmp"
    echo $folder/$table_space"_auto_ddl"/${tabname}"_AUTO_"${schema}.sql
    print $schema.$tabname;
done < $folder/tables_ddl_list.log
```

This is an example of one value

MCLM.OPPP

Parses the values into 2 variables
So After echoing out $schema I would expect MCLM
echoing out $tabnameI would expect OPPP

But I will get empty string

I'm using kornshell and I think its the older version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the double quotes when you read in the values of the variables, and use double quotes in the $table variable, eg :

```
schema=$(echo "$table" | cut -d'.' -f1)
tabname=$(echo "$table" | cut -d'.' -f2)
```

Comment: One can have *both* the outer and inner quotes -- there's no conflict between them, as a command substitution has its own quoting context. That said, putting the quotes around `"$table"` was indeed necessary.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy why is quoting causing the issue here?  `.` has no special meaning to word splitting, right?  `var=a.b; echo $var | cut -f1 -d.` would yield `a`, right?

Comment: @codeforester, necessary for the general case; didn't mean to speak to any specific data. That said, if `IFS=.`, then we'd lose it in the `echo $var`.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your loop more efficiently like this, using `read`, without the need for using an external command like `cut` for each field to be extracted:

```
while IFS=. read -r schema table _; do
    # your logic
done < "$folder/tables_ddl_list.log"
```

The third argument to `read`, `_` is for safety - if the input has more than one dot on a line, all the extra values would be captured by `_`. Optionally, you could add error checking based on whether `_` gets set or not.

Related:

- [Read tab-separated file line into array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9736202/6862601)
- [Looping through the content of a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41646525/6862601)

Comment: This assumes that there is exactly one dot on each line. Maybe `read -r schema table _` to discard anything after the second dot.

Comment: Great point, @tripleee. Updated the answer.